# Data extraction from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, extract

I have the following input:

```
ID,       Last,      First,   Lecture, Tutorial, A1,  A2, A3,   A4,  A5
10034567, Smith,     Winston, L01,     T03,      6,   5.5, 8,   10,  8.5
10045678, Lee,       Bruce,   L02,     T05,      4.5, 6.5, 7,   7,   8.5
00305678, Obama,     Jack,    L01,     T05,      10,  10,  9,   9.5, 10
00567890, Brown,     Palin,   L02,     T03,      4,   7.5, 6.5, 0,   5
10012134, Harper,    Ed,      L01,     T03,      10,  9,   7.5, 10,  6.5
10014549, Johnson,   Andrew,  L01,     T05,      10,  0,   10,  5.5, 7
10020987, Clockwork, Milan,   L02,     T03,      10,  8.5, 8,   9,   9
10021234, Freeman,   Skyski   L01,     T02,      0,   10,  10,  10,  8.5
EOF
```

The first line of the file explains each column of the data. Let n be the total number of students, then the next n lines of the file each corresponds to a student in the class, and contains 10 fields:

1. Student ID
2. Last name
3. First name
4. Lecture section
5. Tutorial sectiom
6. Grades for Assignments 1 *(and so on...)*

Assuming the grades are stored in a file `grades.txt` then you can read an entire line of the file into a Python string s by using the following Python statements:

```
file = open (‘grades.txt’, ‘r’)
s = file.readline()
```

You just need to open the file once, then you can use the `readline()` function multiple times, to read a successive line each time. After the n lines of student records, the file ends with a last line that says `EOF` short for `End of File`.

The number n is not known a priority. The sample input doesnt matter it can contain from 100 to 300 students, in a file named `grades.txt` We wish to eventually draw a histogram for grade distribution of Assignment 1. Therefore you need to extract the
grade of A1 for each student, by processing his/her corresponding line in the file. Construct a list that will have one entry for each student, storing his/her A1 grade. Each time you extract a new A1 grade, append it to this list.

So far this is what I've have done:

```
file = open('grades.txt','r')
s = file.readline()


for line in file:
    newline = str(line)
    grades = newline.split(",")
    if len(grades)<=4:
        break
    elif len(grades)>5:
        break
    else:
        grades = [float(x) for x in grades]
gradeA1 = grades[5]
print(gradeA1)
```

However I only get the first grade `6` and not the other A1 grades for any consecutive lines, all the A1 grades should be compiled into a list.

I have this as my edited code but I still get an error.

```
file = open('grades.txt','r')
s = file.readline()

for s in file:
    s = file.readline()
    grades = s.split(",")
    if grades=='EOF\n':
        break
A1grades = [float(x) for x in grades[5]]   
print(A1grades)
```

I get an index out of range error.

Comment: the csv module will be invaluable http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be that you are not reading all lines from the file...
maybe you could do something like this

```
firstLine = file.readline()
#extract from first line, the number of lines that next

for x in range(1,number_of_line)
    line = file.readline()
    #process the information for all next lines
```

This is a way for do it, hope this could helps you...

Comment: yes that makes sense ! how could i incorporate this into my existing code ?

Comment: when you read the firstLine (s in your case) you need read n (will be the lines that will have your file), then inside the for (for x in range(1,n)) you will read the current line, and then split by ',' and then parse the information, and then save it, and then....

Comment: oh ok I understand! I would show you what i have but It wont let me put code into a comment for some reason.

Comment: That is because the code is for questions and answers, if you want do so, you could add an answer.

Comment: oh i see ok. Well thanks for your help ! i understand how it works but i just dont know how to put it all together.. :( i am very new to python and i'm having difficulties with it still !

Comment: could you show me what the code for it would look like ? im having a hard time trying to fix mine.

Answer (score 1):

For any well-formed data, the csv module is a good place to start - I suggest you have a read of the documentation for that, and give it a try.  Should get you moving in the right direction.  Otherwise, I suspect you've got some confusion on what your list is - a list of results from the most recent line, or a list of lines.  The code currently re-creates grades on each line, which may not be what you're trying to do...

Comment: csv module ? ok ! well i should get a list of A1 results, but the current code i have only gives me the first result, in this case '6'. I'm not sure if its because my loop doesnt repeat for the rest of the lines. It should be able to extract A1 grades for any n number of lines. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but, with this input:

```
ID,       Last,      First,   Lecture, Tutorial, A1,  A2, A3,   A4,  A5
10034567, Smith,     Winston, L01,     T03,      6,   5.5, 8,   10,  8.5
10045678, Lee,       Bruce,   L02,     T05,      4.5, 6.5, 7,   7,   8.5
00305678, Obama,     Jack,    L01,     T05,      10,  10,  9,   9.5, 10
```

and this (part of the) code:

```
for line in file:
    newline = str(line)
    grades = newline.split(",")
    if len(grades)<=4:
        break
    elif len(grades)>5:
        break
```

you only keep looping when there are exactly 5 columns. I count 10 columns (split by a comma). So, you immediately break after the first line (never converting the grades to a float either), and just get the results from the first line only.

There are several other mistakes in your code, but you may want to fix this first.

Btw, I assume this is from a Python course (seen the phrasing in your question), so I take it you're just learning the basics. If not or you want to do this better, I'd go with KevinL and use the [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

**edit**

From the new code (in the edited question):

1. you don't have to check for `EOF`. Loooping through the file (`for s in file`) does that for you.
2. `for s in file` already reads a line. No need for `s = file.readline()` again.
3. For each splitted line, find the grade. Append this to a *different list* that you created (empty) at the start. This list contains your A1 grades.

   grades = []
   for s in file:
       columns = s.split(",")
       grades.append(columns[5])

But: I think you need to step back, write very carefully what either your code is doing (or my code), or what needs to be done (not in code, in words, step by step). There is a lot you are missing, programming wise (not even Python wise).

If this is homework, perhaps it's better to discuss it with other people who do this. Also, there is the [Python tutor mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor), which may be more suited.

No offense, just trying to give some practical advice.

Comment: how can i make it better ? i understand what you're saying, but i dont know how to fix the code :( could you help ? like I what i wrote is as far as i get :(

Comment: I can help, but, have you actually tried taking the remark about the number of columns into account? I.e., try fixing that first (should be straightforward), edit your question with any updated code and let us know how things work (or not). I realise SO isn't really a tutorial site, but it isn't a "here's your code; have fun" site either.

Comment: i understand sorry. i did manage to fix on it though,i said 'for s in file: s=file.readline() / grades=s.split(",") / if grades=='EOF\n': break / A1grades=[float(x) for x in s[5]] / print(A1grades)' but i keep getting an ined out of range error :(

Comment: hey thanks for the advice. The only reason I posted here because i've already gone to everyone i could for help. But i think thats what i am missing. Yea sorry i am terrible at programming in general..